# How can I subclass a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subclassing

Subclassing Pandas classes seems a common need, but I could not find references on the subject. (It seems that Pandas developers are still working on it: *[Easier subclassing #60](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/60)*.)

There are some SO questions on the subject, but I am hoping that someone here can provide a more systematic account on the current best way to subclass `pandas.DataFrame` that satisfies two general requirements:

1. calling standard DataFrame methods on instances of MyDF **should produce instances of MyDF**
2. calling standard DataFrame methods on instances of MyDF **should leave all attributes still attached to the output**

(And are there any significant differences for subclassing *pandas.Series*?)

Code for subclassing `pd.DataFrame`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class MyDF(pd.DataFrame):
    # how to subclass pandas DataFrame?
    pass

mydf = MyDF(np.random.randn(3,4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
print(type(mydf))  # <class '__main__.MyDF'>

# Requirement 1: Instances of MyDF, when calling standard methods of DataFrame,
# should produce instances of MyDF.
mydf_sub = mydf[['A','C']]
print(type(mydf_sub))  # <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

# Requirement 2: Attributes attached to instances of MyDF, when calling standard
# methods of DataFrame, should still attach to the output.
mydf.myattr = 1
mydf_cp1 = MyDF(mydf)
mydf_cp2 = mydf.copy()
print(hasattr(mydf_cp1, 'myattr'))  # False
print(hasattr(mydf_cp2, 'myattr'))  # False
```

Comment: see here for a nice example: https://github.com/kjordahl/geopandas; note that in general IMHO their isn't a reason to ever sub-class, composition works much better, is more flexible, and offers more benefits.

Comment: I think there are reasons to want to subclass, atm it doesn't work, as stated in the linked issue - it's never been priority (though some work has been done towards it...)

Comment: @Jeff: Can you please recommend a way to use composition on `pandas.DataFrame`? Thanks! (Please also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569005/error-in-copying-a-composite-object-consisting-mostly-of-pandas-dataframe).)

Comment: See the 0.16 docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures)

Comment: @Jeff: Thank you for the useful link! However, I don't see a recommended way of composition there. So do you know what goes wrong in the error I got in the link I gave in my last comment? Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff It seems to me that inheritance is a fundamental feature of object oriented programming, independent of anyone's views about composition vs inheritance. The difficulty of subclassing DataFrame makes using the package significantly less attractive to me and I guess many others, judging from the issue reports on the pandas GitHub page.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance#Drawbacks succinctly summarizes the issue. I just want to add one little method to DataFrame...

Comment: so patch in a method; subclassing is almost always a bad idea for a rich complex object

Comment: @Jeff I also have a nontrivial codebase. I am not in a position to chase down whether the patch has propagated through all the import statements in all the modules.

Comment: For Requirement 2, `pd.DataFrame` inherits its `copy()` method from [`NDFrame`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/generic.py#L199). Look at its`_attrs` builtin attribute.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is now an official guide on how to subclass Pandas data structures, which includes DataFrame as well as Series.

The guide is available here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#extending-subclassing-pandas

The guide mentions this subclassed DataFrame from the Geopandas project as a good example: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/geodataframe.py

As in HYRY's answer, it seems there are two things you're trying to accomplish:

1. When calling methods on an instance of your class, return instances of the correct type (your type). For this, you can just add the `_constructor` property which should return your type.
2. Adding attributes which will be attached to copies of your object. To do this, you need to store the names of these attributes in a list, as the special `_metadata` attribute.

Here's an example:

```
class SubclassedDataFrame(DataFrame):
    _metadata = ['added_property']
    added_property = 1  # This will be passed to copies

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return SubclassedDataFrame
```

Comment: It is ambiguous whether `_metadata` refers to class variables or instance variables. This example  has a class var. Can somebody clarify about `self.??` vars?

Comment: The `finalize` method solves Requirement 2 when objects are merged or concat-ed.  I figured out by imitating the GeoPandas code, just search for it and the fix is pretty clear to see.

Answer (score 18):

For Requirement 1, just define `_constructor`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class MyDF(pd.DataFrame):
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MyDF


mydf = MyDF(np.random.randn(3,4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
print type(mydf)

mydf_sub = mydf[['A','C']]
print type(mydf_sub)
```

I think there is no simple solution for Requirement 2. I think you need define `__init__`, `copy`, or do something in `_constructor`, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class MyDF(pd.DataFrame):
    _attributes_ = "myattr1,myattr2"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MyDF, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], MyDF):
            args[0]._copy_attrs(self)

    def _copy_attrs(self, df):
        for attr in self._attributes_.split(","):
            df.__dict__[attr] = getattr(self, attr, None)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        def f(*args, **kw):
            df = MyDF(*args, **kw)
            self._copy_attrs(df)
            return df
        return f

mydf = MyDF(np.random.randn(3,4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
print type(mydf)

mydf_sub = mydf[['A','C']]
print type(mydf_sub)

mydf.myattr1 = 1
mydf_cp1 = MyDF(mydf)
mydf_cp2 = mydf.copy()
print mydf_cp1.myattr1, mydf_cp2.myattr1
```

Comment: It seems to me that you'd often what to have a corresponding subclass of Series at the same time (i.e. have them MyDF and MyS link in some way so e.g. mydf.sum() returns a MyS...)