# subclassing pandas Series and DataFrame: When combining subclassed series into subclassed data frames, the series loose metadata

Tags: python, pandas, subclassing

I have

```
class MySeries(pd.Series):
    _metadata = [_md]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        md = kwargs.pop('md', None)  #md is series
        super(TimeSeries, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if md is not None:
            try:
                self._md = self._md.append(md)     
            except AttributeError:
                self._md = md

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MySeries

class MyFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MyFrame    

    @property
    def _constructor_sliced(self):
        return MySeries


md_a = pd.Series(...some content...)
md_b = pd.Series(...some other content...)
a = MySeries(...some a content..., md=md_a)
b = MySeries(...some b content..., md=md_b)
```

Tim now everything is fine:
    a._md
gives the content of md_a. So does b.

No I create my MyFrame with :

```
f = MyFrame([a,b]).T
```

or

```
f = SecuritiesFrame()
f = pd.concat((f, a, b), axis=1)
```

Now I try to get the metadata:

```
f.iloc[:,1]._md
```

I get an AttributeError: 'MyFrame' object has no attribute '_md' as the metadata is not propagated.

Is this a normal behavior or am I overseeing something? Do I have to track the metadata myself separately in my subclass of DataFrame which would be very inconvenient.

Comment: metadata is not copied unfortunately you'd have to keep track of this yourself

Comment: Any worthwhile example upon which I could build apart from geopandas?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22161058/4077912) might help...

Comment: Take a look at the `__finalize__` method. It copies metadata for some, but not all situations. I'm working on something similar right now and investigating fow to override it to handle what I want.