# Why does subclassing a DataFrame mutate the original object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subclass

I am ignoring the [warnings](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#extending-subclassing-pandas) and trying to subclass a pandas DataFrame.  My reasons for doing so are as follows:

- I want to retain all the existing methods of `DataFrame`.
- I want to set a few additional attributes at class instantiation, which will later be used to define additional methods that I can call on the subclass.

Here's a snippet:

```
class SubFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        freq = kwargs.pop('freq', None)
        ddof = kwargs.pop('ddof', None)
        super(SubFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.freq = freq
        self.ddof = ddof
        self.index.freq = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset(self.freq)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return SubFrame
```

Here's a use example.  Say I have the `DataFrame`

```
print(df)
               col0     col1     col2
2014-07-31  0.28393  1.84587 -1.37899
2014-08-31  5.71914  2.19755  3.97959
2014-09-30 -3.16015 -7.47063 -1.40869
2014-10-31  5.08850  1.14998  2.43273
2014-11-30  1.89474 -1.08953  2.67830
```

where the index has no frequency

```
print(df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2014-07-31', '2014-08-31', '2014-09-30', '2014-10-31',
               '2014-11-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Using `SubFrame` allows me to specify that frequency in one step:

```
sf = SubFrame(df, freq='M')
print(sf.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2014-07-31', '2014-08-31', '2014-09-30', '2014-10-31',
               '2014-11-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

The issue is, this modifies `df`:

```
print(df.index.freq)
<MonthEnd>
```

What's going on here, and how can I avoid this?

Moreover, I profess to using [copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155951/how-to-subclass-pandas-dataframe) code that I don't understand all that well.  What is happening within `__init__` above?  Is it necessary to use args/kwargs with `pop` here? (Why can't I just specify params as usual?)

Comment: The typical use-case for subclassing is to modify/extend the base class functionality in some way.  You're not really doing that here.  You're simply setting up your DataFrame in a specific manner.   Rather than subclass, you might want to simply create a factory type function/object that simply returns a DataFrame constructed in the way that you want.  Subclassing doesn't seem to make a lot of sense for this particular use-case.

Comment: "create a factory type function/object that simply returns a DataFrame constructed in the way that you want."  Can you elaborate on that please?  Right now what I have is a standard `Class(object)` where the dataframe is an attribute.  And yes, I am extending the functionality by defining more than a handful of other methods, not shown here.

Comment: Look at piRSquared's second suggestion with the pipe.  Notice he's not subclassing.  He's creating a function that simply returns a DataFrame in the way you want it set up.  There's no need to subclass.  You're not changing behavior.  One of the uses of a factory class is to create the object set up in the way you want it.  If you want to base a new DataFrame on a copy of the first, you would create a function that takes the existing DataFrame as a parameter, copies it, adds your frequency, and then returns the copy.  No subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll add to the warnings.  Not that I want to discourage you, I actually applaud your efforts.

However, this won't the last of your questions as to what is going on.

That said, once you run:

```
super(SubFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

`self` is a bone-fide dataframe.  You created it by passing another dataframe to the constructor.

Try this as an experiment

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(1, list('AB'), list('XY'))
d2 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

d2.index.name = 'IDX'

d1

     X  Y
IDX      
A    1  1
B    1  1
```

So the observed behavior is consistent, in that when you construct one dataframe by passing another dataframe to the constructor, you end up pointing to the same objects.

To answer your question, subclassing isn't what is allowing the mutating of the original object... its the way pandas constructs a dataframe from a passed dataframe.

Avoid this by instantiating with a copy

```
d2 = pd.DataFrame(d1.copy())
```

---

What's going on in the `__init__`

You want to pass on all the `args` and `kwargs` to `pd.DataFrame.__init__` with the exception of the specific `kwargs` that are intended for your subclass.  In this case, `freq` and `ddof`.  `pop` is a convenient way to grab the values and delete the key from `kwargs` before passing it on to `pd.DataFrame.__init__`

---

How I'd implement `pipe`

```
def add_freq(df, freq):
    df = df.copy()
    df.index.freq = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset(freq)
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2]), pd.to_datetime(['2017-03-31', '2017-04-30']))

df.pipe(add_freq, 'M')
```

Comment: I follow you except for "Avoid this by instantiating with a copy."  Where would `copy()` go within `super(SubFrame, self) ...` and why?  I would've suspected `self.copy` based on how `super` works but that's throwing error

Comment: I'm not sure I'd make `SubFrame.__init__` force a copy (read that as I'm truly not sure.  I could swayed either way).  Because you'd be changing something that pandas does.  Instead, I'd change how you created your variable `sf`: `sf = SubFrame(df, freq='M')` to this instead `sf = SubFrame(df.copy(), freq='M')`

Comment: Okay--and there are 2 alternatives to subclassing suggested [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures)--would you say that either of those apply to what I'm trying to do in this specific case?

Comment: I'm not certain what composition is as I've not studied many CS concepts.  But I believe composition is what I do.  I create a new object class in which the dataframe is an attribute.  I manage everything else that way.  I believe that `pipe` will do the trick for you... I'll update my post with an example.

Comment: Ahh okay. Then composition is what I have now (before I tried subclassing).  Will probably end up using `pipe` here, appreciate the edit