# custom pandas.DataFrame class

Tags: python, pandas, oop, dataframe, inheritance

I have created a class based on a `pandas.DataFrame` object which initializes with a `csv` file as shown here:

```
import pandas as pd

class CustomDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    def  __init__(self, input_file):
        df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
        super().__init__(df)
    #...
```

This way, I have a `CustomDataFrame` type that has additional specific methods to operate on itself. The problem I have with this setup is that when I take a slice of the object, it returns a `pandas.DataFrame` object instead of keeping the same type. In other words:

```
> blip = mypackage.CustomDataFrame('test.csv')

> type(blip)
mypackage.CustomDataFrame

> type(blip[1:3])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Is there a simple way to correct my custom class such that it can operate on itself in all the ways that a `pandas.DataFrame` can, while returning this custom class each time rather than just the built-in version of the `DataFrame`?

Comment: I have seen it said by one of the top 3 Pandas answerers that subclassing a DataFrame is a _bad idea_.

Comment: Oh really? That throws a wrench in my plans. Could you please link me to some of those answers? And do you know what a better alternative would be? Thanks.

Comment: I don't recall exactly what the other issue was, but I spend plenty of time looking at SO questions and this is only the second that I recall that was using subclassing tbh. It might be better to flesh out your plan with one of the custom methods that makes you think you need to subclass in the first place.Why can't you just have an object that applies methods to its own DF attribute?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22155951/6361531