# How to use and print the pandas dataframe name

Tags: python, pandas, variables, global

I have a pandas dataframe

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':a, 'col2':b})
```

I dont want to use df.name, but i want to print dataframe name *df* and also can use somewhere like saving csv

```
print(df + '.csv')
```

I am expecting

```
'df.csv'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the name of a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727333/get-the-name-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544919/can-i-print-original-variables-name-in-python & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. Why don't you try using a dictionary instead.

**Example**

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]

var_map = {'df':pd.DataFrame({'col1':a, 'col2':b})}

# Save all dataframes in dictionary with name
for key in var_map:
    var_map[key].to_csv(key + ".csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can subclass `pandas.DataFrame` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155951/how-to-subclass-pandas-dataframe). It is a little tricky but possible...
2. You can add an attribute directly to the instance of DataFrame. Not recommended but possible.
3. You can also create a class containing a DataFrame and overload the `__repr__` and `to_csv` methods as mentioned below

Here is an example of the 2nd solution

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':a, 'col2':b})
df.myname ='my_super_name'
```

Here is an example of the 3rd solution

```
import pandas as pd

class MyDataFrame():
    def __init__(self, _myname, *args, **kwargs):
        self.myname = _myname
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.myname

    def to_csv(self):
        self.df.to_csv(self.myname + '.csv')

a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]

df = MyDataFrame('my_data_frame', {'col1':a, 'col2':b})
print(df)
df.to_csv()
```