# Python: can an object have an object as a "default" representation?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I am just getting started with OOP, so I apologise in advance if my question is as obvious as 2+2. :)

Basically I created a class that adds attributes and methods to a panda data frame. That's because I am sometimes looking to do complex but repetitive tasks like merging with a bunch of other tables, dropping duplicates, etc. So it's pleasant to be able to do that in just one go with a predefined method. For example, I can create an object like this:

```
mysupertable = MySupperTable(original_dataframe)
```

And then do:

```
mysupertable.complex_operation()
```

Where original_dataframe is the original panda data frame (or object) that is defined as an attribute to the class. Now, this is all good and well, but if I want to print (or just access) that original data frame I have to do something like

```
print(mysupertable.original_dataframe)
```

Is there a way to have that happening "by default" so if I just do:

```
print(mysupertable)
```

it will print the original data frame, rather than the memory location?

I know there are the *str* and *rep* methods that can be implemented in a class which return default string representations for an object. I was just wondering if there was a similar magic method (or else) to just default showing a particular attribute. I tried looking this up but I think I am somehow not finding the right words to describe what I want to do, because I can't seem to be able to find an answer.

Thank you!
Cheers

Comment: If you want to be able to access any attribute/method of the original df, maybe you want to [subclass Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155951/how-can-i-subclass-a-pandas-dataframe)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `MySupperTable` class, do:

```
class MySupperTable:

    # ... other stuff in the class

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.original_dataframe)
```

That will make it so that when a `MySupperTable` is converted to a `str`, it will convert its `original_dataframe` to a `str` and return that.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an object to `print()` it will print the object's string representation, which under the hood is retrieved by calling the `object.__str__()`. You can give a custom definition to this method the way that you would define any other method.